# Get ordered product size and color in order items admin grid in Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

I am showing a list of items ordered from all the orders from 'sales_flat_order_item' table in Magento 1.9.2 . I get the name ,Sku and all other values from the following collection.

```
  protected function _prepareCollection() {

    $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection();
    $collection->getSelect()->join(array('o' => 'sales_flat_order'), 'main_table.order_id = o.entity_id', array('increment_id','created_at'));
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    parent::_prepareCollection();
    return $this;
}
```

Now I want to get the size and color of the item ordered.  I am new to Magento , i have no clue from where I can get these value.

Answer (score 0):

these values are serialized inside the column product_options in order items with the key attributes_info. here is an example

```
array (size=10)
  'info_buyRequest' => 
    array (size=6)
      'uenc' => string 'aHR0cDovLzUwLjU2LjIxMy4xNTcvd29tZW4vdG9wcy1ibG91c2VzL25vbGl0YS1jYW1pLTQ2MC5odG1sP29wdGlvbnM9Y2FydA,,' (length=100)
      'product' => string '417' (length=3)
      'related_product' => string '' (length=0)
      'super_attribute' => 
        array (size=2)
          92 => string '20' (length=2)
          180 => string '78' (length=2)
      'qty' => string '1' (length=1)
      'return_url' => string '' (length=0)
  'attributes_info' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'label' => string 'Color' (length=5)
          'value' => string 'Black' (length=5)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'label' => string 'Size' (length=4)
          'value' => string 'L' (length=1)
  'simple_name' => string 'NoLIta Cami' (length=11)
  'simple_sku' => string 'wbk002' (length=6)
  'product_calculations' => int 1
  'shipment_type' => int 0
  'giftcard_lifetime' => null
  'giftcard_is_redeemable' => int 0
  'giftcard_email_template' => null
  'giftcard_type' => null
```